# Using recursion to prove Cantor Shroeder Bernstein's theorem

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-set-theory

I was asked to prove the Bernstein Theorem using pre-given definitions:

Given two injective functions: $f: A\rightarrow B$ and $g: B\rightarrow A$

a) Define $C_0=A\backslash g(B)$ and $C_n=g(f(C_{n-1}))$ for all $n\ge 1$. Prove that $C_k\cap C_m=\varnothing$ for all $k\neq m$.

b)Let $C=\bigcup_{n\in \Bbb N}C_n$. We define $h:A\rightarrow B$:

$$h(x) =
\begin{cases}
f(x),  & \text{if $x\in C$} \\
g^{-1}(x), & \text{if $x\notin C$}
\end{cases}
$$

Show that h is well defined

I have no idea how to prove the first question...I did watch a few videos on how this partition of set works, but to be honest i didnt get it...

One video mentioned something (as i understood it): $C_n=g(f(C_{n-1}))\subseteq g(B)$ and hence $C_n\bigcap C_1=\varnothing$. And inductively, $C_k\bigcap C_m=\varnothing$...Could someone clear this up for me? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without loss of generality assume $k < m$. Suppose for a contradiction that there is $c \in C_k \cap C_m$. Then by definition of $C_k$ there must be $a \in C_0 = A \setminus g(B)$ with $(gf)^k(a) = c$. Here $(gf)^k$ stands for $k$ applications of $gf$, where $(gf)^0$ is  just the identity map (to cover the case $C_k = C_0$). Similarly, there must be $a' \in C_0$ with $(gf)^m(a') = c$. Hence $(gf)^k(a) = (gf)^m(a')$, so by injectivity we must have $a = (gf)^{m-k}(a')$. Because $k < m$ we have $m - k \geq 1$. So this means that $a$ is in the image of $g$, but that contradicts $a \in A \setminus g(B)$. We have thus arrived at our contradiction and conclude that we must have $C_k \cap C_m = \emptyset$.

Comment: Since $k < m$, shouldn't we have $a = (gf)^{m-k}(a')$?

Comment: Oops, of course, it's fixed now.

Comment: Hi sorry I didn't get what $(gf)^k$ means....it means $C_k$? It looks like the definition of it .....

Comment: I mean the k application is the same as $C_k$ right?I mean instead of $C_n$....just different index

Comment: @JerryCohen Indeed, $C_k = (gf)^k(C_0)$. The point of writing it like $(gf)^k$ is that we then can use injectivity of $g$ and $f$ (and so $gf$ is injective).

Comment: And sry just one follow up question, you say there must be an $a\in C_0$, why is that? The definition of $C_k$ would be the same as $C_n$ right?  So if k is greater 2 then that wouldn't be correct right? Sorry I have many questions, I really don't get the partition thing every one talks about in this Bernstein theorem

Comment: @JerryCohen We have $C_k = (gf)^k(C_0)$, so if $c \in C_k$ then that is just saying that $c \in (gf)^k(C_0)$. That means exactly that $c$ is in the image of $C_0$ under $(gf)^k$, so there must be $a \in C_0$ with $c = (gf)^k (a)$.

Comment: Ouh sorry I meant why $C_k=(gf)^k(C_0)$ I mean unless k=2 that's not the case right ?

Comment: It really is the case, e.g. $C_3 =gf(C_2) = gf(gf(C_1)) = gf(gf(gf(C_0))) = (gf)^3(C_0)$. If you want to be precise you could prove the $C_k = (gf)^k(C_0)$ by induction.